# Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx.currentTest.commands; Not Working

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, cypress, e2e-testing, mochawesome

CONTEXT: I use cypress 8.7.0. and on support/commands.js I have a function than get the commands foreach execution using `Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx.currentTest.commands;`

*| function in support/commands.js*
[image]

*| Result:*
[image]

This work succesfull when execute the commands from "cypress open" and run test since UI of cypress.
But failed when use commands "cyress run" return undefined.

I search understand why not working both ways.

Comment: Did you create a config file?, if not try adding a [config file](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Configuration-File), make sure the browser is defined